# Is it possible to upgrade a machine remotely using local system resources?

Tags: upgrade, remote, chroot

I'm doing an upgrade on a little Intel Atom "nettop". It's extremely slow and takes somewhere around an hour to do a release upgrade. I'm looking to improve that. This question follows a slightly different idea from my last one: [Can you have debs without compression?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369499/can-you-have-debs-without-compression)

My desktop is a beast. It's not but it's more powerful than several dozen Atoms. It's also on the same gigabit network as the nettop. Would the following be possible over SSH/NFS/whatever:

- Mount the remote system to something local (eg /mnt/) using NFS or something else
- Mount local resource over the top (eg /proc/, /sys/, et al)
- Chroot into /mnt/
- Perform an upgrade using command line tools.

What I'm describing is *similar* to (and very much inspired by) [chrooting to restore Grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_ChRoot). Something I've suggested a few times and have performed more than once. It works for Grub but would it work for a remote system?

What problems am I likely to run into? Is the system going to grab the right updates (nettop is 32bit, desktop is 64bit)? Is the fact this is a live system going to interfere with the upgrades?

Am I just being silly? Should I just to a normal upgrade?